# Laravel checkbox problem which I cannot update the pivot table

Tags: laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I'm working on a laravel application. In laravel I'm trying to update a row from a pivot table. In this application I have three tables:

> *issues:*  id, title, description
>
> *categories:* id, name
>
> *category_issues:(**pivot table**)* id, issue_id, category_id

In laravel I'm trying to update a row from a pivot table. I have this relationships: 
Issue.php

> public function categories() { 
>         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_issues');
>      
>  }

Category.php

> public function issues() { 
>         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Issue', 'category_issues');
>      
>  }

*A issue can have many categories.*

Html code for displaying category section:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Category :') }}</label>
                    <div class="form-check col-md-6">
                      @foreach ($categories as $category)

                        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->id }}"
                        {{ in_array($category->id, $issue->categories->pluck('id')->toArray())  ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                        <label for="{{ $category->id }}"> {{ $category->name }} </label>
                      @endforeach
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Here is the update function file:

```
public function update(Issue $issue)
{
  request()->validate([
      'title'=> ['required', 'min:3'],
      'description'=> ['required', 'min:3'],
      'category' => ['required']
    ]);
  $issue->title = request('title');
  $issue->description = request('description');
  $issue->save();

  //Category_Issue Update
    $categoryIssue = new CategoryIssue;
    $cats = request('category');

     foreach ($cats as $cat) {
       $categoryIssue->updateOrCreate([
         'issue_id'=> $issue->id,
         'category_id' => $cat
       ]);
     }
     return redirect('issues')->with('success', 'Issue has been updated');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the creation / update on the **CategoryIssue** model (do you even have a **CategoryIssue** model?), Laravel makes this really easy to update the pivots of a relationship all at once, with the `sync()` method.  You've set up the relationships correctly already per your code above.

In your `update()` method, you already have your **Issue** model, and have saved it.  You have a set of categories coming in from the form via the `$request` object (or none if user didn't choose any), so you can then update the pivot like this:

```
$issue->categories()->sync($request->get('category', []));
```

Leaving a blank array as the second argument is optional.  One small suggestion: maybe make the name of the field on the form 'categories' instead of 'category' just to keep it easy to remember it is an array coming in.